# Which dragons survived the Dance of the Dragons?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire, dragons

During Dance of Dragons we know exactly which dragons died in combat or riots:

The slain dragons included Vhagar, Caraxes, Syrax, Arrax, Tyraxes, Vermithor, Sunfyre, Vermax, Dreamfyre, Greyghost, Seasmoke, Morghul, Shrykos, Tessarion, Moondancer, Stormcloud & Meleys the red Queen.

We know that [Sheepstealer](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Sheepstealer) slipped away during the dance with his rider and was never seen again. But at least he survived.

To provide some idea of which dragons might have survived, list of surviving Targaryens would be helpful. The surviving members of House Targaryen at end of the dance were following:

1. [Aegon the Younger](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegon_III_Targaryen) - Lost his dragon [Stormcloud](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Stormcloud) while escaping from forces of the three daughters.
2. [Jaehaera Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Jaehaera_Targaryen) - Lost her dragon [Morghul](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Morghul) during [storming of dragonpit](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Storming_of_the_Dragonpit)
3. [Rhaena Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Rhaena_Targaryen_(daughter_of_Daemon)) - Lost her hatchling hours after birth. Eventually bounded to dragon [Morning](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Morning). Morning survived the dance.
4. [Baela Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Baela_Targaryen) - Lost her dragon [Moondancer](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Moondancer) in fight against Sunfyre the golden.
5. [Viserys II](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Viserys_II_Targaryen) - Presumably Lost his egg during captivity in hands of [Kingdom of three daughters](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Triarchy).

I believe that TWOIAF names four dragons to be known survivors of the dance.

So far I have been able to name only two:

1. Sheepstealer
2. Morning

Which are the other two dragons who survived the civil war?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As it happened however, I found the answer right before posting the question in [TWOIAF](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0553805444) but reckon this will be helpful if someone else is wondering about this in the future.

The other two dragons which survived the dance were:

1. [Silverwing](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Silverwing)
2. [Cannibal](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Cannibal_(dragon))

Silverwing went mad and wild after the dance. She fled west and made her lair on an island in [Red Lake](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Red_Lake), hunting and killing as she would. She was never ridden by anyone again. Since she was not the last Targaryen dragon we can assume she died before 153 AC (The year in which last official Targaryen dragon died).

Cannibal mysteriously disappeared after the Dance during reign of King Aegon III. No information is provided on its fate. We also do not know if anyone tried to claim Cannibal after death of [Silver Denys](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Silver_Denys).

In any case, to sum it up, four dragons survived the War which are:

1. Sheepstealer
2. Morning
3. Silverwing
4. Cannibal

Comment: Sounds about right from what I remember. Nice self-answer!